# Exporting primefaces:Tree to pdf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tree

I have a tree structure displayed on my webpage. The nodes are dynamically created from the data retrieved from the database. I want the entire tree(exlpoded view) to be exported to a pdf file. How can I achieve this using a java library? I am using JSF2.1 with primefaces 3.5. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try primefaces data export.http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporter.jsf

Comment: primefaces data exporter is for datatables: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporterHome.jsf

Comment: @rags is right. primefaces data export only works for the datatables on the page.

Comment: @Tankhenk I couldnt find any example that helps. COuld you please provide mw with an example that does the required.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I found this "plug-in", check it out: https://github.com/rdicroce/jsfexporter